# Restricting SSH users to certain access permissions

Tags: permissions, sshd

Is there a method to restrict SSH users to certain access rights for certain programs (such as Python, Perl, Ruby, Java, etc), but also a method to restrict them from leaving their `/home/` directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to restrict a user to /home, ssh is not really the right tool. For example, /bin/bash is not in /home. A better tool would be something like NFS, sshfs, ftp, etc (we could debate which one to use).

You could build a chroot in /home, but [LXC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXC) is, IMO, a better more modern tool.

Your other option would be to write an apparmor profile. This would be somewhat similar to a chroot in that you would need to specify what a user would and would not have access to in a profile.

What you would do is make a link to /bin/bash , I call it `jailbash`

```
sudo ln /bin/bash /usr/local/jailbash
```

You then change the users log in shell from bash to jailbash

```
sudo chsh <user>
```

Now write an apparmor profile for `jailbash`. Here is [an example](https://github.com/nthomson-pivotal/apparmor-profiles-release/blob/master/jobs/apparmor-profiles/templates/usr.local.bin.jailbash). You will need to review and update it, but it gives you a starting point.

Comment: Given that this is on a shell server, i need to at least get restrictions done for programs, would you recommend apparmor profiles, or LXC, for a low-spec shells server?

Comment: Hard to answer your question without more details on what you want your users to do. In general, Apparmor if your users need to interact with the main system (start/stop services, edit config files, manage web content, backups, etc) and LXC if they need only ssh/shell access (sshfs, port forwarding).

Comment: the ssh/shell access is all they'd need, but i'd like to restrict the running of non-admin-installed python programs, i.e. `python ./IAmAScript.py`, from the shell.

Comment: My advice would be to use apparmor.